# Flask, Ajax, get value in url for ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery

In python, I have

```
@app.route('/update_account/<account_id>', methods=['POST'])
def update_account(account_id):
```

In html form, I have:

```
<form id="update_account_form" name="update_account_form" action="{{ url_for('update_account', account_id=account._id) | safe }}" method="POST">

URL: http://<domain>/edit_account/5b9fbe55fb6fc072da02e2f6
```

In AJAX, I have:

```
  $(function () {
  $('#update_account_form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    account_id = 5b9fbe55fb6fc072da02e2f6
    $.ajax({
      url: '/update_account/'+account_id,
      data: $('#update_account_form').serialize(),
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
```

My question is, how do I read the value of 5b9fbe55fb6fc072da02e2f6 from the url to use it in my AJAX call.
Do I use some jQuery regex system to read the url and work out the id, or is there some other clever way that I can pass the id from the html url via ajax to flask on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` after getting url.

```
$(function () {
      $('#update_account_form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = window.location.href;
        account_id = url.split("/").pop();
         ...........
```